# Intersection of ellipsoid & hyperplane, inequality chain.

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

If $S$ is an ellipsoid in $\mathbb{R}^n$ centered at the origin, then, in suitable orthonormal coordinates $x_1, \dots, x_n$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $S$ can be defined by the inequality$$\sum_{j = 1}^n a_j x_j^2 \le 1,$$where$$0 < a_1 \le a_2 \le \dots \le a_n$$are uniquely determined by $S$. Let $H$ denote a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ passing through the origin; then $S \cap H$ is an ellipsoid in $H$, and $H$ is a Euclidean space of dimension $n-1$. Hence $S \cap H$ determines a sequence of coefficients$$0 < b_1 \le b_2 \le \dots \le b_{n-1}.$$What is the easiest way to see that$$a_1 \le b_1 \le a_2 \le b_2 \le \dots \le a_{n-1} \le b_{n-1} \le a_n?$$

Comment: Google Cauchy interlacing theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Intuition

Think of intersection $\, S\cap H\,$ as orthogonal projection of ellipse $\,S\,$ on hyperplane $\,H.\,$

- Projection operator is *injective*, which means that diameter of projection is always less than or equal to diameter of original set. 
  Therefore we conclude that for any coefficient in inequality for projection  $\, S\cap H\, $ there is a *larger* coefficient in inequality for the original ellipsoid $\, S.\, $
- On the other hand, projecting onto hyperplane reduces dimension of geometrical figure. 
  Using this fact we can show that for any coefficient in inequality for $\,S\cap H\,$ there will be a certain number of *lesser* coefficients in inequality for $\,S.\,$
- Above facts combined with  pigeonhole principle result in $\,a_1 \le b_1 \le  \dots \le a_{n-1} \le b_{n-1} \le a_n.\,$

---

## Proof

Let us rewrite  ellipsoid inequalities in terms of semi-principle axis  $\, \alpha_i:=a_i^{-1/2}\,$ and $\, \beta_i : = b_i^{-1/2}\,$
$$
\left.
\begin{aligned}
S &= 
\left\lbrace x = 
\left[ \begin{smallmatrix}x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{smallmatrix} \right] 
\in \mathbb R^n \, \bigg\vert \; \ \sum_{j = 1}^n a_j x_j^2 \le 1
\right\rbrace
&& = \left\lbrace x \in \mathbb R^n \, \bigg\vert \; \ \sum_{j = 1}^n \left( \frac{x_j}{\alpha_j} \right)^2 \le 1
\right\rbrace
\\
S\cap H &=\left\lbrace x = 
\left[ \begin{smallmatrix}x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_{n-1} \end{smallmatrix} \right] 
\in H \subseteq \mathbb R^{n-1} \, \bigg\vert \;\ \sum_{j = 1}^{n-1} b_j x_j^2 \le 1
\right\rbrace 
&& = \left\lbrace x \in H^{\phantom{n}} \, \bigg\vert \; \ \sum_{j = 1}^{n-1}\left( \frac{x_j}{\beta_j} \right)^2 \le 1
\right\rbrace
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
Coefficients $\,\alpha_i\,$ equal to semi-principle axis $\,\vec{\boldsymbol{v}}_i\,$ of ellipse $\,S\,$ and can be defined iteratively:

- $\, E_1 : = \mathbb R^n \,$ Euclidean subspace,
- $\, S_1 := S\,$ original ellipse in $\,\mathbb R^n\,$
- $\displaystyle\,\vec{\boldsymbol{v}}_1: = \left\lbrace \overrightarrow{UV} \; \  \Big\vert \; \ \  \max_{U,V \in S}  \left\|V - U \right\|\right\rbrace\,$ – vector connecting two most distant points of ellipse $\,S.\,$
- $\, \alpha_1 := \left\| \vec{\boldsymbol{v}}_1 \right\|\,$  *diameter* of ellipse $\,S\,$ $%\,\vec{\boldsymbol{e}}_{1}:=\dfrac{\vec{\boldsymbol{v}}_1}{\left\| \vec{\boldsymbol{v}}_1 \right\|} = \dfrac{\vec{\boldsymbol{v}}_1}{\alpha_1}\,$

For $\, j=2, \dots, n\,$ compute

- $\, E_j := E_{j-1} \ominus \left\lbrace \vec{\boldsymbol{v}}_{j-1} \right\rbrace\,$ orthogonal complement of span of $\,\vec{\boldsymbol{v}}_{j-1}\,$ in $\, E_{j-1} \,$
- $\, S_j:= S_{j-1}\cap E_{j}\,$ projection of ellipse $\,S_{j-1}\,$ onto Euclidean space $\, E_{j-1} = \mathbb R^{n-j+1}.\,$
- $\, \vec{\boldsymbol{v}}_j\,$ vector connecting two most distant points of ellipse $\,S_j.\,$
- $\, \alpha_j:= \left\| \vec{\boldsymbol{v}}_j \right\|\,$ diameter of $\,S_{j}\,$

By replacing ellipses $\, S_j\,$ with their projections to hyperplane $\,h\,$ we can define coefficients $\,\beta_i\,$ in inequality for $\,S\cap H.\,$

#### Upper Bound

Note that coefficient $\,\alpha_j\,$ can be viewed as the *size* of ellipsoid along direction of $\,j^{\,\text{th}}$ basis unit vector $\,\vec{\boldsymbol{e}}_{j},\,$ i.e. as a size of *orthogonal projection* of $\, S\,$ on $\vec{\boldsymbol{e}}_{j}$.

The intersection $\,S\cap H\,$ of ellipsoid and hyperplane is also an orthogonal projection of $\,S\,$ onto $\,H,\,$ i.e.
$\,S\cap H = P_H S\,$ where $\,P_H\,$ is the operator projecting its argument onto hyperplane $\,H.\,$
Since orthogonal projection is *injective*, the size of intersection $\,S\cap H\,$ along $\,\vec{\boldsymbol{e}}_{j}\,$ is always less than or equal to the diameter of the original ellipsoid $\,S.\,$
Therefore  for any $ j=1, \dots, n-1,\,$ there exist $\, i = 1 , \dots, n\,$ such that $\,\beta_j \le \alpha_i.\,$

#### Lower Bound

Let us show now that for any $\, \beta_j, \ j = 1, \dots, n-1,\,$ there exist $\, n-1\,$ coefficients $\,\alpha_j\,$ which are less than or equal to $\,\beta_j.\,$
Assume $\,\vec{\boldsymbol{v}}_1\,$ is the smallest semi-principle axis of $\,S\,$ of the size $\,\alpha_1.\,$ 
Consider following possible cases:

1. $\,\vec{\boldsymbol{v}}_1 \cap H = \vec{\boldsymbol{v}}_1 \implies \vec{\boldsymbol{v}}_1 \in H\,$ – the smallest semi-principle axis of $\,S\,$  lies entirely in hyperplane.
   Projection does not have affect the smallest semi-principle axis of ellipse, so that  $\,\alpha_1 = \beta_1.\,$
2. $\,\vec{\boldsymbol{v}}_1 \cap H \neq \vec{\boldsymbol{v}}_1 \implies \vec{\boldsymbol{v}}_1 \not \in S\cap H,\,$ i.e. $\,\vec{\boldsymbol{v}}_1\,$ is **not** the smallest semi-principle axis of the projection ellipse $\,S\cap H.\,$ 
   But then the new smallest semi-principle axis of $\,S\cap H.\,$ will be larger or equal to $\,\vec{\boldsymbol{v}}_1,\,$ so that $\, \alpha_1 \le \beta_1.\,$
3. Combining results from two previous steps we conclude that $\, \bbox[3pt, border:1pt solid #001100]{\alpha_1 \le \beta_1.}\,$

We can repeat procedure above iteratively to show that for any coefficient $\,\beta_j, \  j=1,\dots, n-1,\,$ of projected ellipse $\,S\cap H\,$ there exist  at least $\, j-1\,$ coefficients $\,\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_{j-1}\,$ of original ellipse $\,S\,$ less than or equal to $\,\alpha_j.\,$
$$
\forall  j=1,\dots, n-1, \ \exists \,\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_{n-j} \, : \quad 
\bbox[5pt, border:1pt solid #000000]{\beta_j \ge \alpha_{j-1} \ge \cdots \ge \alpha_1}
$$

Using Dirichlet's principle  we get
$$
\bbox[3pt, border:2pt solid #F90000]{\alpha_1 \le \beta_1 \le \alpha_2 \le \beta_2 \le \dots \le \alpha_{n-1} \le \beta_{n-1} \le \alpha_n}
$$

Substituting back expressions for coefficient $\, a_i = 1/ \alpha_i^2, \  b_i = 1/ \beta_i^2\,$ and reverting enumeration we get
$$
\bbox[3pt, border:2pt solid #F90000]{a_1 \le b_1 \le a_2 \le b_2 \le \cdots \le a_{n-1} \le b_{n-1} \le a_n}
$$

*Q.E.D.*